# Is there a way to get notified when a lambda function is deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to aws. I tried using cloud watch logs for the same and custom metrics but the issue is if the lambda is not triggered I was not able to find the logs for the same.

Comment: You can use EventBridge for this. Create a rule for the delete lambda event and configure whatever trigger you need

Comment: By the way, lambda not getting triggered and getting deleted are two different things.